# Member 'DALfile.tocity(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

`Member 'DALfile.tocity(string)'` cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

I'm new in C# and I don't know what does it mean and how to get rid of it...

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when tocity() method in DALfile class is 'static'. I am assuming that DALfile is an instance of the class that you have created. You can't access a static method using an instance reference. You can refer to the method by using the class name instead. If DALfileClass is the class of DALfile instance, you can probably do DALfileClass.tocity(string)